# Can a Docker image have more than one digest?

Tags: docker

I notice that when I use `docker inspect image someimage`, the RepoDigests value is an array rather than just a string. Is there some situation where an image can have more than one digest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated before: Yes a docker image can have more than one digest when there is more than one version of a tag.

At first glance this doesn't appear to make any sense, but after seeing this I understood it immediatly:

- Let's check a random tag of the [official node image in docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/node/18.12.1-alpine3.16/images/sha256-b78c9500958805b52214e8bd588defe55ec32116dfdc094e3ca652a3502d67df?context=explore)

[image]

[image]

- As you can see there is a different digest for each OS/Architecture, and this is one reason why we need to be able to distinguish one version of a Tag from another...

Comment: An image can technically have many digests even when they're all for the same architecture. This is because Docker Hub provides a ManifestList which contains the different digests for the different architecture. When pulling an image by a tag, docker will get the digest of the ManifestList by default. If you pull the image with the specific digest for your architecture, docker will show both the ManifestList and Manifest digests as RepoDigests for the image.

Comment: @a544jh Indeed, the digest doesn't have anything to do with the architecture, it's simply a hash of the image. I did talk about the architecture just because it's a nice example of a use case, in fact, it's the example that made me get it. The ManifestList is news to me and I thank you for the additional knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a digest for the multi-platform manifest (a listing for all the platform specific images), this is what docker shows by default to make multi-platform support easier. There could be a second entry for the platform specific image. And if you push/pull the image to/from other registries you'll also see those locations listed in the array (commonly seen when you have a local registry with a copy of upstream base images).

Historically it's also possible to pull an image with an old manifest schema and docker would push with a different schema, changing the digest. And if you pull+tag+push to copy your image to another registry, it's possible for the digest to change because tooling that generated the manifest may be different (there are multiple media types for the image manifest, and serializing the JSON can reorder/add/remove fields or change the white spacing).

Without using containerd to directly manage the images (currently experimental), one pulled image will not have multiple platforms. Docker dereferences the the multi-platform manifest to your local platform and only pulls that single image.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, docker images can have many digests.

Comment: In what situation?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/images/ "As long as the input used to generate the image is unchanged, the digest value is predictable". In other words, you can get multiple digest values if you have multiple versions of your image. It's a bit like a checksum.

Comment: Wouldn't changing the build inputs result in a different image, though?